# Change the name of [reactor]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

`reactor` is a design pattern and `project-reactor` is a library which is related to Java Spring project.

It seems that a lot of developers choose the wrong tag [reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactor) instead of [project-reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project-reactor). To avoid this kind of problem and avoiding losing good questions which are located under the wrong tag, I suggest that we change the name of [reactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactor) to [reactor-design-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactor-design-pattern) or anything similar.

Comment: `reactor-pattern` would also work, I think.

Comment: Then blacklist [reactor]? Else either use could recreate it.

Comment: So, instead of reactor, maybe [nuclear wessel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdSJFrhb-HM)?

Comment: @Machavity I read that as "nuclear *weasel*" and was much amused.

Comment: "React to [reactor]"